how can i give shadow to Container and TextFields in flutter
i want to add shadow to my container widget but something is not right,  what i want is mentioned in this image,

this is my container()
Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 35),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                    ),
                    child: TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2),
                            child: Image.asset(
                                'assets/images/icons/facebook.png',
                                height: mQHeight / 30),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(width: mQWidth / 50),
                          Text(
                            "Continue with Facebook",
                            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),


You can use boxShadow in decoration like this:
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.white,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
      boxShadow: [
        BoxShadow(
          color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
          spreadRadius: 2,
          blurRadius: 3,
          offset: const Offset(0, 3),
        )
  ]),
  // other code
)

Also, I removed the border and added color. And result is (I've remove the image):

